# How to display a timer in activity in Android

Tags: android

I want to show timer, with every second. After 20 seconds I want that activity to call itself.

But when I don't display the timer it waits for 20 seconds as I wish to do but as soon as I implement code to display timer it just starts and suddenly stops suddenly.

Here is my code. Please help me out.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
public int time=20;
Button end;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread timerdisp = new Thread(){
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

        public void run(){
            try{    
                sleep(1000); // sleep for 1 seconds
                tv.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                time-=1;
                if(time==0){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));                        
                }
                run();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }; 
    timerdisp.start();
    );
}
```

Comment: where is "time" declared?

Answer (score 2):

Android provides a better facility of [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), may be you should use that. As it provides many inbuilt methods and runs on background thread by default.

You can use `onFinish()` method to execute your call to the activity.

Here is an [example](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/simple-countdowntimer-example/) of the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below Code:

```
private long ms=0;
    private long splashTime=2000;
    private boolean splashActive = true;
    private boolean paused=false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Hides the titlebar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread mythread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (splashActive && ms < splashTime) {
                        if(!paused)
                            ms=ms+100;
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                finally {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, Home.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        mythread.start();
    }
```

and you can try this also

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    public TextView text;
    private final long startTime = 20 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));
        countDownTimer.start();

    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),xxxx.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `runOnUiThread`

This acts as a normal `Thread` and will not allow your UI to sleep.
 and the system will not hang.

or you can also use `AsyncTask`. I will prefer you using `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Correction running on UIThread when you select `Thread.sleep(time)` it will sleep the main application for the time that means the application will hang. But ya it is good to go with `AsyncTask`

Answer (score -1):

**Use below code to call the function for every 20 seconds.**

```
private Timer timer;
TimerTask refresher;                 

timer = new Timer();    
refresher = new TimerTask() {
  public void run() {
                            // your code to call every 20 seconds. 
                     };
                 };
// first event immediately,  following after 20 seconds each
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(refresher, 0,1000*20);
```

**Use below lines to show the time :**

```
package com.example.test;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Long startTime;
public native String getLastShotName();
public native String colorNormal();
public native String flipImage();
public native String forceInvertColor();
public native String getLastTitle();
public native String myMethod();
boolean mbFlip = false;
private Timer timer;
private Handler handler = new Handler();  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);           
          TimerTask refresher;
             startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
             handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimer);
             handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 1000);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
         handler.postDelayed(updateTimer, 1000);
    }         
    private Runnable updateTimer = new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                      Long spentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;                  
                      Long minius = (spentTime/1000)/60;                          
                      Long seconds = (spentTime/1000) % 60;
                      time.setText(minius+":"+seconds);
                      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                  }
              };
}
```

Comment: With a reputation of +1.5k, it is expected that your answers be more well formatted. Please take care of keeping SO cleaner. You had more empty lines than code. Indentation was terrible.